# Reprojecting shapefile to raster projection

Tags: coordinate-system, rasterization, landsat-8

I need to rasterize my shapefile. This can only happen if both raster and shapefile are in same projection. I don't know if they are in same projection.

How do I compare the projection of these two files?

**Vector layer**

I converted my csv to shapefile using gdal and vrt file.

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="tomato">
        <SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="1">tomato.csv</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS>
        <GeometryField reportSrcColumn="false" encoding="PointFromColumns" x="longitude" y="latitude"/>
        <Field name="name" src="name" type="String" />
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

My csv was in format (name,longitude,latitude)

I got the projection of this shapefile using the following code.

```
layer = dataSource.GetLayerByIndex(0)
spatial_ref = layer.GetSpatialRef()
proj4 = spatial_ref.ExportToProj4()
print('Layer projection is: {proj4}\n'.format(proj4=proj4))
```

The layer projection turns out to be

```
Layer projection is: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

**Raster layer**

My raster layer is landsat 8 rgb color composite tiff file.
The projection of this tiff file is

```
proj = dataset.GetProjection()
print('Image projection:')
print(proj + '\n')

output : 

PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 43N",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",75],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","32643"]]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55270/discussion-on-question-by-sinhavartika-reprojecting-shapefile-to-raster-projecti).

Comment: @iant was'nt aware of this feature of stackexchange. Thank you